# Redis 4 systemd Sentinel config file not writable

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

I have installed latest Redis 4(4.0.14) version.I am trying to setup a 3 node Redis sentinel. I changed my sentinel config file , when I try to run

```
/usr/bin/redis-sentinel /etc/redis-sentinel.conf
```

I could start redis sentinel however If i start using systemd,

```
systemctl start redis-sentinel
```

I am getting,

`2331:X 03 Jun 23:30:31.744 # Sentinel config file /etc/redis-sentinel.conf is not writable: Permission denied. Exiting...` .

Why does using systemd result in the above error? I have default systemd redis-sentinel configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file permission on /etc/redis-sentinel.conf

Check for SELINUX `sestatus` and if it's running, then try disabling it or add an selinux exceptions.